# How do we load images from web to the ViewFlipper dynamically in android?

Tags: android, image, viewflipper

I have plan to design module which needs to show up 75 & more pictures from the web in it.After a general research about ViewFlipper I find only static images can be loaded into it.I tried ImageGallery it takes much longer time.Any suggestion on how to load dynamic image in ViewFlipper.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by utilizing the Url Image View Helper, https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

You can look at a sample implementation here:
https://github.com/manijshrestha/ViewFlipperDynamic

Hope this helps.